# @font-face ttf dont showup (bar-code)

Tags: html, css, font-face

I'm using the code below. The fonts `hand` and `volk` load properly but the third (`cepnet`) doesn't.

```
@font-face {
    font-family:"hand";
    src:url("hand.ttf") format("TrueType");
}

@font-face {
    font-family:"volk";
    src:url("volk.ttf") format("TrueType");
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "cepnet";
    src:url("ECTSymbol.ttf") format("TrueType");
}
```

Why doesn't it load?

These fonts are from different sources, so I'm not sure if there's any type of copyright or file format, only that the third one is barcode-character font. Could that be a reason?

All files are in the same directory and spelled correctly.

*EDIT:*Using Firefox 9.x on Windows system. The html is the following:

```
<span style='font-family: cepnet, Sans-Serif; color: #f60;'>/046240608\</span><br />
<span style='font-family: hand, Sans-Serif; color: #f06;'>/046240608\</span><br />
<span style='font-family: volk, Sans-Serif; color: #6f0;'>/046240608\ Hello</span><br />
```

And using `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN' http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd'>`

*UPDATE:* Also I've tested the font on windows using the font viewer and the characters (bar-codes) appear correctly. Alson on windows office app the font is correct. It seems to be a browser issue since i've tested it on [this site](http://fontdragr.com/) and the result was not the bar-codes.

Comment: Could you post the CSS that uses these fonts, and the associated HTML?

Comment: Take a look at the Inspector in Chrome. Chances are, it will show you some errors.

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't load"? Do you mean the page is blank, or something is giving an error message?

Comment: Page loads properly, 2 fonts showing up as expected but the third one.

Comment: On the inspector the response header is 304-Not Modified. So the font was download and is avaiable to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're the font from this page: [ECTSymbol.TTF](http://code.google.com/p/sa2condominio/downloads/detail?name=ECTSymbol.TTF)

Most of that font is empty spaces, only `/1234567890:` and a few other values will show up.

Comment: Yes, using only numbers and valid characters.